# cmake config mode

Tags: c++, cmake

Если у меня есть header-only библиотека и есть xxxConfig.cmake, я делаю find_package(xxx CONFIG REQUIRED). Как получить include директорию?

Comment: Наверное, это делается так: get_target_property(xxx_INCLUDE_DIRS xxx INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)

Comment: В зависимости от того, как написан config, но обычно, согласно соглашению, они именуются как `xxx_INCLUDE_DIR`.

Comment: Он же может быть сгенерирован автоматически?

Comment: да, если он грамотно написан

Comment: Вы имеет ввиду, если CMakeLists грамотно написан, то можно сгенерировать хороший Config?

Comment: Файл `xxxConfig.cmake` может быть: 1. Написан "руками" 2. Сгенерирован автоматически при сборке проекта. В первом случае способ работы с результатом `find_package(xxx)` зависит от того, что написано в `xxxConfig.cmake`. Во втором случае способ работы зависит от кода (`CMakeLists.txt`), которым сгенерирован файл. Если этот файл генерировался по таргету `xxx` (или `xxx::xxx`, или какое-либо другое имя), то способ, описанный в Вашем первом комментарии, должен работать.